# How do i use selenium to click "Accept All Cookies" on a cookie pop up?

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am currently trying to learn selenium in Python and I am having an issue clicking the "Accept All Cookies" button.

I am using:

Python v3.9

Chrome v87

This is the HTML page i am trying to scrape

https://www.currys.co.uk/gbuk/tv-and-home-entertainment/televisions/televisions/samsung-ue75tu7020kxxu-75-smart-4k-ultra-hd-hdr-led-tv-10213562-pdt.html

Here is my code currently

```
    # Selenium Tutorial #1
    
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
    
    import time
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\Ste1337\Desktop\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe")
    
    driver.get("https://www.currys.co.uk/gbuk/tv-and-home-entertainment/televisions/televisions/samsung-ue75tu7020kxxu-75-smart-4k-ultra-hd-hdr-led-tv-10213562-pdt.html")
    
    #search = driver.find_element_by_id(ContentPlaceHolder1_NotifyBtn)
    
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    
    
    link = driver.find_element_by_id("onetrust-accept-btn-handler")
    link.click
    
    try:
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))
        )
        element.click
    except:
        driver.quit()
```

Comment: ```link.click()``` you must call the function by adding the brackets ```()```

Answer (score 1):

The "( )" is missing after the click.
Try this:

```
    link = driver.find_element_by_id("onetrust-accept-btn-handler")
    link.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply wait and click.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("https://www.currys.co.uk/gbuk/tv-and-home-entertainment/televisions/televisions/samsung-ue75tu7020kxxu-75-smart-4k-ultra-hd-hdr-led-tv-10213562-pdt.html")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
```